# Create refresh button in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services

I have two rectangle in SSRS report. In First rectangle I've 5 text box. Exp.

One

Two

Three

For

Five

I need that when I click on a textbox, the data in another rectangle is displayed.
For example, I click on the textbox with the name "One" and in the other rectangle it displays 'One'. I explained as best I could) It's possible?

Answer (score 2):

Add a parameter to the report which will get the rectangle value.
Make the parameter hidden.

Then on each textbox, you will create a link(Jump to report) to the same report, passing the rectangle value as the parameter value.

Set the rectangle value to be equal to the parameter.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please, can you give me example? Or more details

Comment: I have added some images to assist you

Comment: Thank you! Can you give me report.rdl example?

Comment: You can download it from here: https://wetransfer.com/downloads/d670dafc2b87d1ce7b92fd4b8d28be0320170822103933/5aa1a7